# PostgreSql describe tables for a forum

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm building a forum.
Here is how I want the setup:

[image]

My problem is that I'm using `SERIAL PK` for my `Id`'s. I don't know if that's the best option for production but my `Topics` should be able to link to both `Forum` or `Subforum` as I don't want to create 2 tables for each, also I would have to create 2 replies tables for each `Topic` table.

Would I need to create unique `ids` on all tables? Then I could link `Topics` and `Replies` to different tables? If so, how I would do that?

Comment: Forum can be a tree structure with id, parent_id fields

Comment: Do you mean I should have different tables for each and not mix? like for eg. Subforum_topics and forum_topics (for replies as well)

Comment: A single table instead of two, `Forum (id, parent_id, category_id)`

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck/unsure following what published presentation of what method? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS Especially not photos of handwriting. PS An ERD augments DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: diagram]

I believe you need something like this. As mentioned by Marcodor - forum can also be a subforum. I just edited your diagram a little bit.

For instance if forum is a subforum parent_forum_id is set to it's parent forum, therefore if it is a parent forum parent_forum_id is set to null.